# how to sort the records by another field for the top_hit in ES

Tags: elasticsearch

I have data such as:

```
Id  name startTime(timestamp)   
1    c     1510000000000  
2    c     1500000000000    
3    a     1510000000000   
4    a     1500000000000    
5    b     1500662700000
```

I want to get the max `startTime` record for each `name`, and then sort by `name`.
the result should be:

```
Id  name startTime(timestamp)
1    a     1510000000000
5    b     1500662700000
2    c     1510000000000
```

currently, I can get the max `startTime` group by each `name`, but I don't know how to sort by `name` for the results.

Here is my query:

```
GET index/default/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "group": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "tops": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "startTime": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Comment: If you've already aggregated over `name` why would you want to sort `top_hits` by the same field?

Comment: actually I want to sort top_hits by the startTime, and then I want to sort the bucket results by the name.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm understand, except for `top_hits` sort, you want the `name` buckets to be sorted by the `name`.

Have a look at [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order) order. All you have to do is to add `order` by key under the `terms` aggregation.

Here is my suggestion:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "group": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name",
        "order": {        --> this will do the trick
          "_term": "asc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "tops": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "startTime": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but I got exception below:
caused_by": {
      "type": "aggregation_execution_exception",
      "reason": "Invalid term-aggregator order path [_key]. Unknown aggregation [_key]"
    }